# onclick event not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I'm using jQuery and Bootstrap 3. Every thing is working fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE.

My script is like this:

```
var resultCount = 0;
var funct= "onclick=renderData("+Id+","+resultCount+")";
var html_text='</div>';       
html_text='<a style="display:block;" class="result-series-link col-sm-6"          href="#collapse_1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionxyz"'+funct+'>Content for this sectiuon</a>';
html_text+= '   </div>'; 
html_text+='<div id="accordion_'+resultCount+'" class="panel-group sub-panel-group    result-panel-group ">';
html_text+='                </div>';

function renderData(id, i){

  $('#accordion_'+i).html('');
  var htmlcontent = '<div>someData</div>;
  $('#accordion_'+i).append(htmlcontent);
}
```

Hence this htmlcontent is not appending in $('#accordion_'+i) only in case of IE.

Comment: You have an unclosed string. var htmlcontent = '<div>someData</div>; You need a closing ' before ;

Comment: Do you get any output in internet explorer?

Answer (score 2):

You did not close your string on this line:

```
var htmlcontent = '<div>someData</div>;
```

should be

```
var htmlcontent = '<div>someData</div>';
```

This might be causing the problem.

Comment: this is not the issue . over here i forgot to put " ' " . thing is content is not loading in div with id "accordion_i" . and same is working in chrome and firefox

Answer (score 0):

I would advise not injecting raw text like that, I'd always build these things via the DOM, creating the nodes and appending them to a parent.

I built a library for use in my job and I had a few issues with things not quite being recognized properly. I found that it was just easier to use the DOM API to do it.

Just something to consider.

Comment: is there any other solution for this . becoz my content is too big . and if i change the script using DOM it will take a lot of time . same thing is working fine in IE 11 . but not in the earlier version

Comment: Older versions of IE will likely operate in 'quirks mode', I'd invest the time into using the DOM API, because then you explicitly tell the browser what you want to do, rather than inject HTML and hope that the browser does the right thing.

You see, browsers will attempt to bend over backwards to attempt to do what it thought you meant, rather than what you said. 

This can manifest as closing tags on it's own and doing its best to create a valid DOM, so it is best to be explicit in what you mean than leave it up to the browser.